# Fail to compute specific second order ordinary differential equation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, ode

I'm trying to compute an 2nd ODE in python with matplotlib

with the quatiion 2(A-X)*y''=sqrt(1+(y')^2)

I try to assume u=y' to solve the ODE

but the result shows that NameError: name 'u' is not defined in return np.array(u)

which is very weird.

However, I don't really know that my method can work or not.

How can I fix that?

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

A=1

def diff(u, x):
    return np.array(pow(1+pow(u,2),0.5)/(2*(A-x)))


def diff(y, x):
    return np.array(u)


x = np.linspace(0, A, 100)  
u = odeint(diff, 0, x)  //f(1)=0

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.grid()
plt.plot(x, y)  
plt.show()
```

I've done by putting diff(u, x) in return np.array but it still fails to work.

Comment: You have two functions `diff()`, which is already an issue. I think the second one should be renamed or remove altogether. Currently, the second function overwrites the the first function, but it doesn't really do anything: it just (tries to) return an array. It turns `u` in array, but `u` is not known inside that function: `x` and `y` are given as arguments, and that's about it. Remove the second `diff()` and you might be good to go.

Comment: Also, `//` is C++ style comments. Use a `#` instead.

Comment: Note that in your function, when x approaches A, values become very large, since you start to (nearly) divide by 0 (`A - x`). That's probably not what you want; you'll need to work around that singularity (for example, don't create `x` to go all the way to `A`).

Comment: Well, you could integrate it once to get a first-order ODE. That should make life a little easier. dy/dx=sinh[C-(1/2)ln(A-x)], where C is a constant.